# select-where clause outs different results

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, validation, date

I got this query in my SQL Server 2008 procedure

```
insert into tableXYZ(ID, CODPROY, NOMPROY, TITOBS, OBSERVACION, RECOMENDACION, RESPUESTA, UNIDRESP, CONTACTO, FECHAEMISION, RIESGO, ULTIMAACTUALIZACION, FECHAVENCIMIENTO, ESTADO, FECHACARGATC, REGULADOR, REGULADO) 
  select 
     ID_Obs, CodigoProyecto, NombreProyecto, TituloObservacion, Incidencia, 
     Recomendacion, Respuesta, UnidadResponsable, Propietario, 
     case when isdate(FechaEmision) = 1 then CONVERT(DATETIME, FechaEmision, 103) end, 
     Riesgo, EstadoActualizacion, 
     case when isdate(FechaRevisada) = 1 then (CONVERT(DATETIME, FechaRevisada, 103)) else (case when isdate(FechaEstimada) = 1 then CONVERT(DATETIME,FechaEstimada,105) end) end,
     Estado, 
     case when isdate(FechaCargaTC) = 1 then CONVERT(DATETIME, FechaCargaTC, 103) end,
     Grupo, 'BCPPE' 
  from 
     @myTableType 
  where 
     GRUPO <> '467' and GRUPO <> '912' and GRUPO <> '910' and GRUPO <> ''
```

As you can see this query has many cast methods, the problem is that the results of this sentence is so differente between two users. Can you give me some clues?

PD: Look this part:

```
case when isdate(FechaRevisada) = 1 then (CONVERT(DATETIME, FechaRevisada, 103)) 
     else (case when isdate(FechaEstimada) = 1 then CONVERT(DATETIME, FechaEstimada, 105) end) 
end
```

This part of the query works right with me, but do not with my partner.

Comment: Yeah here's a clue: "don't do that."

Comment: You say different users...are these occurring on different databases, by chance?  I'm wondering if there's an internationalization problem with the dates. (specifically the isdate() function)

Comment: I have a server client app in .net that consume information from BD, when I run the app in my pc (with windows authentication) the result is ok, but when other guy run the app, the app does not work as I expected.

Comment: What happends when neither `FechaRevisada` nor `FechaEstimada` is a valid date? What's supposed to happen?

Comment: Execute the following SQL for both you and your partner and tell us the results: `select date_format, language
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where session_id = @@SPID`.

Comment: @nurdglaw I supposse the null value comes.

Comment: @RBarryYoung my dateformat is dmy and my partner has mdy. That's why the different query results.

Comment: @Rakibro:  Yep.  You can correct that with the `SET DATEFORMAT` command.